# Where can I ask a question whose topic is programming but with a general vision?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Stack Overflow seems to be oriented to very concrete questions attached to a technology. So, where should I post if I want to discuss and be informed about a more general question like "how does company handle large amount of user data" or "how does automation tools manage different web browsers".

Comment: While those are good questions, as I look at the [list of Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) I don't see any that would take those questions. Pekka's answer may be the solution for you.

Comment: To me these questions sound a bit like DevOps stuff. According to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134306/where-do-i-post-questions-about-dev-ops), SO, SuperUser or Programmers can be appropriate; depending on the type of question. If it is a concept question like your first one, I'd say Programmers. If it is related to coding, SO is appropriate. If it is related to sytem administration and configuration, SuperUser might be a better place. I admit though, that often the boundaries are quite fuzzy

Answer (score 12):

I'm afraid the answer is "nowhere on the Stack Exchange network."

[Quora](http://www.quora.com) is one place where some types of these questions may work.

Comment: Yeah or "anywhere else on the net". Discussion forums, IRC, ...